# Find differences in data between two SQL server tables

Tags: sql-server, join

I have two tables `Customer_staging` and `Customer`. The customer_staging table has the fields `customer_num`, `birth_date` and `birth_month` and this table gets refreshed every day. Any new additional records from this table should be updated into the actual `Customer` table. Also, any records that do not match in values for `birth_date` and `birth_month` should be updated into the `Customer` table.

I tried the below query.

```
Select customer_num, birth_date, birth_month from Customer_Staging
EXCEPT
Select customer_num, birth_date, birth_month from Customer
INNER JOIN Customer_Staging ON Customer_Staging.customer_num = Customer.customer_num
```

I am getting the results I want, however, I am getting more number of records. I have added the inner join in the second part of the query thinking that the resultset will be confined to the table that has lesser number of records. The Customer_Staging table has 3170 records where as the Customer table currently has only 40 records. For ex, if I have 5 records that match between the two, the result set has 3165 records. However, I would like to get the differences resultset for the records that exist only in the Customer table.

Can someone help?

Comment: I think you need Merge

Answer (score 0):

Nest the select:

```
Select DISTINCT customer_num, birth_date, birth_month from Customer_Staging
WHERE customer_num NOT IN (Select customer_num
                           From Customer)
```

Comment: [**`except`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-except-and-intersect-transact-sql) removes duplicates.